# Gnosis Safe Create Delegate Key API 400

Tags: gnosis-safe

I am trying to create a delegate in rinkeby testnet through the api following the doc in [here](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-docs/blob/devportal/docs/tutorial_tx_service_set_delegate.md). I got an 400 response and not quite sure what happened. Can you check and see if anything is wrong?

```
const dayjs = require("dayjs");
const {ethers} = require("ethers");
const axios = require("axios");

const SAFE_ADDRESS = 'SAFE_CONTRACT_ADDRESS'
const MNEMONIC_SEED = 'SAFE_OWNER_SEED'
const DELEGATE_ADDRESS = 'DELEGATE_ADDRESS'
const TX_SERVICE_BASE_URL = 'https://safe-transaction.rinkeby.gnosis.io'


const main = async () => {
    try {
        const now = dayjs().unix();
        const time = ethers.BigNumber.from(now).div(3600)
        const hash = ethers.utils.keccak256(`${DELEGATE_ADDRESS}${time.toString()}`)
        const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(MNEMONIC_SEED)
        const signature = await wallet.signMessage(hash);

        const result = await axios.post(`${TX_SERVICE_BASE_URL}/api/v1/safes/${SAFE_ADDRESS}/delegates/`, {
            "safe": SAFE_ADDRESS,
            "delegate": DELEGATE_ADDRESS,
            "signature": signature,
            "label": "Delegate_1"
        })

        console.log(24, result.response)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("ERROR")
        console.log(err.message)
    }
}

main()
```

Comment: can you share the response body?

Comment: "Request failed with status code 400"
This is the error message i got from axios

Comment: The response should also contain a body with more details on why a 400 was thrown. A 400 indicates that you are sending invalid data, therefore to help it is required to see the body.

Comment: Oh i saw the error:
  data: { nonFieldErrors: [ 'Signing owner is not an owner of the Safe' ] }

Comment: But i used the owner seed to sign and double check the safe address. Any idea why?

Comment: I think you've used an `eth_sign` signature, for this signature you need to adjust v(last 1 byte of the signature) to be > 30, see https://docs.gnosis-safe.io/contracts/signatures

Comment: How can i do it with ethers js?

Comment: use ethers to generate a signature, and then replace 1 last byte (2symbols) with hex-encoded number > 30

Comment: did you mean at doing this:

array = ethers.utils.arrayify(signature);
array[array.length - 1] = 32;
signature = ether.utils.hexlify(array);